# Issue with document.getElementById for iOS6

Tags: jquery-mobile, appmobi

I have developed a Mobile App using Jquery Mobile.
I am facing issue with this App that on Back click the HTML of page is not rendering.
First time page is loading properly. But when I am visiting that page back button click then its not loading properly means html is not rendering on this page.
In my app all pages having Back button by which i can go back tot he previous page using history.back(); function.

Html of Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Register</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="_appMobi/appmobi.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onDeviceReady() {
                try {
                    AppMobi.device.setRotateOrientation("portrait");
                    var elem = document.getElementById("register_submit");
                    elem.innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn_submit" onclick="SubmitRegistrationForm()" value="Submit" class="inputTypeSubmit" />'; //Error is here Error: Undefined

                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }
            }

            function goback() {
                    history.back();
            }
          document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>  <a id="hrfBack" class="backClassbutton" rel="external" onClick="goback();" href="#">
       <div id="register_submit">
        </div>
        <a href="#" rel="external" title="Login">Login</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am getting error while using elem.innerHTML ="some html"

So why this error coming? Or How to fix it?

Thanks
Dalvir

Answer (score 0):

```
//Hmm. Try an rewrite the code.


<script>

//Something like this will help:

function onDeviceReady(){

try {
//Other codes....
var elem = document.getElementById("register_submit").innerHTML;

    }

catch {
//other codes
      }

}

</script>
```

Create your button in the HTML body tag and ensure the SubmitRegistrationForm function is in your  tag. The SubmitRegistrationForm() is missing. That is why your are getting "undefined" error